# UNITY Localization Portugal (Brazil) and Portugal (Portugal) -> Iphone (IOS) returning same code for both languages

Tags: unity-game-engine, localization, internationalization

I have a unity project on which i use I2Loc, where for Portugal i have "pt" while for Portugal (Brazil) i have "pt-BR". But on IOS devices its returning only

PTB = (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName)
or pt = for (LocalizationManager.CurrentLanguageCode)

i dont know how to find a solution to differentiate between Portugal(Portugal) and Portugal (Brazil)
IOS returning same code for both :(

my head stuck! please help if u ever encountered such problem.

How to differentiate between Portugal(Portugal) and Portugal (Brazil) on IOS devices ?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik `"pt"` is a general wildcard kind of identifier for just any Portuguese and will match also for `"pt-BR"`!

In order to effectively differentiate you would need to use `"pt-PT"` and `"pt-BR"`